# Ruby On Railsで質問に対してのBA機能

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsで知恵袋のようなBA機能を実装しようと奮闘していますが、アソシエーションに対しての理解ができておらずに、はまっています。

やりたいこととしては、投稿されたnoteに対して、note.idを取得する。
また、そのnoteに紐づいたコメントのcomment.idを取得する。
取得した情報をBestAnswerモデルに格納する。
現状の構成とエラーが以下になります。

------------モデル-----------------------

```
class BestAnswer
  belongs_to :note
  has_one :comment
end

class Note
  has_one :best_answer
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :best_answer
end
```

------------コントローラー-----------------------

```
class BestAnswersController < ApplicationController
  def best
    note = Note.find(params[:note_id])
    bestanswer = note.best_answer.build(comment: params[:comment])
    bestanswer.save
    redirect_to (:back), notice: 'hogehoge'
  end
end
```

------------ビュー-----------------------

```
<% @note.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= "#{comment.user.name}さんが、#{comment.body}と言っています %>
  <%= link_to "BAに決定", best_path(:comment => comment.id, :note_id => @note.id), method: :post %>
<% end %>
```

------------エラー------------------------

```
Processing by BestAnswersController#best as HTML
Parameters
{"authenticity_token"=>"DtGJ+4qzzG2PqEJpa7GH9Fb8pQhGDX0cg+w+qhf0tP/9HIIVYabiJeW0rEiL7iydpa5PpjrdR1V1LeGzfOeJjw==", "comment"=>"43", "note_id"=>"36"}
Note Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "notes".* FROM "notes" WHERE "notes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 36]]
Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 43]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 34ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Comment(#70182053951140) expected, got Fixnum(#15377440)):
app/controllers/best_answers_controller.rb:5:in `best'
```

ここで、エラーがでるのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Comment(#70182053951140) expected, got Fixnum(#15377440))

のエラーを読み解くと良いと思います。

Comment オブジェクトを期待しているのに、Fixnum(数字)が渡されたよ、と言っています。
意味は分かるでしょうか？

> note.best_answer.build(comment: params[:comment])

これは、best_answer.build の引数に、comment オブジェクトを渡すコードですね。

しかし、`params[:comment]` に入っているのは、

> best_path(:comment => comment.id, :note_id => @note.id)

ですから、comment.id が入っています。

よって、このミスマッチを解消してあげてください。

html 側で、渡すものがcomment_id であることを明示し、

> best_path(:comment_id => comment.id, :note_id => @note.id)

受け側で

> note.best_answer.build(comment_id: params[:comment_id])

または、

> comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
>   note.best_answer.build(comment: comment)

で良いと思います。

validation を掛けていないなら、下の方が、Commentオブジェクトの存在確認ができる利点があります。

Comment: 詳細なご返答ありがとうございます。

送信するパラメーター名はモデルに作ったパラメーター名と同じものじゃないと動かないということですね。

Postのパラメーター名は変数のように自分で好きに決めて、コントローラーで受け渡し先のカラム名にさえ、渡っていればOKなのだと思っていました・・・

ありがとうございました\(^A^)/